# no module named Pillow._imaging

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

[image: as you can see at he right, the _imaging.c module IS presant]

when i try to

```
import Pillow.selftest
```

no problem.
but, as you can see,

```
import Pillow._imaging
```

raises a importerror. i have been trying to rename the c-module, move it to the Lib folder, importing other (.py) modules in same folder, which works. nothing seems to work, any idea why?

as you can see, im using windows 7, python 3.3 and the pillow fork of PIL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of Pillow are you using? Neither the 1.1.7 or 2.0.0 have `import Pillow._imaging as core` within image.py.

It looks like you have copied the contents of the source archive into Lib without running setup.py, which will be necessary to compile the C modules. Try using the Windows installer available on [PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.0.0)